# css work when applied in browser, but not working in wordpress additional css

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, frontend

From dev tool we can apply

```
border-radius: 20px;
```

to

> .separate-containers .inside-article, .separate-containers
> .comments-area, .separate-containers .page-header,
> .separate-containers .paging-navigation, .one-container .site-content,
> .inside-page-header

where we can see the change immediately, but when we add the below code to WordPress additional CSS section, it doesn't work.

```
@media {    
.separate-containers .inside-article, .separate-containers .comments-area, .separate-containers .page-header, .separate-containers .paging-navigation, .one-container .site-content, .inside-page-header 
{
      border-radius: 20px;
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfdz9.png)

How can we debug? or how can we apply the CSS to WordPress correctly?

Comment: Could you tell us exactly how you are adding it to the WP site?

Answer (score 1):

What is that @media with no follow-up for? just remove it if you don't need to specify anything and it should work as long as the .css file is included in the page (double check that too)